# List all images with a special tag in IBM Cloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I want to list all images that have `v1` tag. I used the following command

```
ibmcloud cr images
```

but, this command list all images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [filter and formatting feature](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Registry?topic=Registry-registry_cli_list):

```
ibmcloud cr image-list --format "{{ if eq .Tag \"v1\" }}{{ .Repository }}:{{ .Tag }}{{end}}"
```